# Number of colorations of intersecting diagonals in an octagon

Tags: combinatorics

Given a regular octagon, in how many ways can we color one diagonal red and another diagonal blue so that the two colored diagonals cross (in the interior)? Consider rotations and reflections distinct.

I tried creating an image of the octagon and testing out how the octagon's diagonals intersected i.e. finding a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Assume you draw the red diagonal first.  Fix one end and you have five choices of where to draw the other end.  There will be six remaining vertices.  The blue diagonal crosses the red diagonal when one end of the blue diagonal is across the red diagonal from the other end.  Count up the possibilities.  Then there were eight choices for the first point, but each configuration has bee counted twice, so multiply by four.

Answer (score 3):

Any four vertices of a regular polygon define exactly one pair of intersecting diagonals, and each such pair is defined by a distinct set of four vertices. For each pair of intersecting diagonals, we choose which will be red; the other will be blue. The number of red/blue colorings of intersecting diagonals of any $n$-gon is therefore $$\binom{n}{4}\times 2$$ For octogon, this is $\binom{8}{4}\times 2=70\times 2=140$ colorings.