# Counting problem involving diagonals (Not duplicate)

Tags: combinatorics

Given a regular octagon, in how many ways can we color one diagonal red and another diagonal blue so that the two colored diagonals cross (in the interior)? Consider rotations and reflections distinct.

---

I know this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014567/number-of-colorations-of-intersecting-diagonals-in-an-octagon) exists, but I don't quite understand the explanation and answer. It would be great if someone could explain it to me again!!

Comment: This is still very much a duplicate, unless you can highlight a particular part of Ross's answer that doesn't make sense to you, or perhaps a particular method you wish to use. Right now, you are asking us to answer again, with basically no further direction, and it makes little sense to do so on a whole new post.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to specify what you don't understand, what you want more detail about, or which methods you'd like to use. You could also just leave a comment under Ross's answer asking for clarification, or post a bounty asking for a more authoritative answer to the question.

Comment: I don't really understand what @Ross is saying. Did they use casework, or what did they use? Also, shouldn't Ross take rotations and that stuff into consideration or am I missing something?

Comment: Ross only provided a hint, suggesting how to count the number of colorings using casework without providing much detail. I have provided an answer for the general case which does not require such tedious counting.

Comment: @MathMagician It looks like casework to me. Draw five separate pictures of the five possible red diagonals coming from a single point. Each picture is a separate case. I agree with Daniel though: his answer is much nicer.